# How to select ListBox item by ValueMember

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, valuemember

I have two items with the same `DisplayMember`, but a different `ValueMember` and want to select one of the two items programmatically, how do I do this?

Items:

```
123 -> Peter Pan
234 -> John Doe
345 -> Peter Pan
```

I cannot select the last "Peter Pan" by doing

```
Listbox1.FindStringExact("Peter Pan");
```

Because this only returns the first occurrence of "Peter Pan".
The following also doesn't work because it only sets the selected item, but doesn't show it in the list:

```
Listbox1.SelectedItem = dataTable.Rows.Find(345);
```

Who can help me with this one?

I found some more info myself, the list is sorted, therefore when I update the `DataTable` (which is used to fill the list) the list is resorted and it seems to select the item that was in place of the edited item.

`Listbox1.FindStringExact` does only work if the `DisplayMember` is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property of your list control:

```
Listbox1.SelectedValue = 345;
```

Comment: this doesn't work either, because then the list still takes the selected index and selects that item (the list is sorted)

Comment: @Michael, `SelectedIndex` does what you say, `SelectedValue` is supposed to lookup the item from its `ValueMember` property. Did you try it?

Comment: @Frédéric The list is sorted, therefore when i change the SelectedValue, the SelectedIndexChanged event fires, I then get the selectedRow by ListBox1.SelectedItem, this returns the selected item item in the list with the index of the selectedvalue, just before that, the sorting changed the way the list is sorted and therefore getting the wrong row

Comment: @Michael, if I understand your issue correctly, you can fetch the selected row with `selectedRow = dataTable.Rows.Find(Listbox1.SelectedValue);`.

Comment: @Frédéric, I know how to fetch the selected row, only when i update the row and the list updates itself, it has the item that was on that place selected.

Comment: @Michael, I'm not sure to understand, so let's recap: 1) you get the currently selected item (how?), 2) you modify the associated row in the `DataTable`, 3) the list box updates that item's position, so another item gets selected, 4) you want to reselect the item you just modified?

Answer (score 2):

You must assign data via DataSource property of ListBox control, not via Items.Add.
After that you can use ValueMember to select items:

```
listBox1.DataSource = GetPeople();
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";

// Now you can use
listbox1.SelectedValue = 345;
```

UPDATE: Items is a member of ListBox class, but SelectedValue is a ListControl property, which can use only DataSource.